# How do I pass a value from one .hbs file to another

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to pass the index value from posts.hbs to the delete-post.hbs and then from delete-post.hbs to my delete-post.js function.

**posts.hbs**

```
<br>
<h2> Blog Posts </h2>
<ul>
{{#each model as |onePost index|}}

    <li id = {{index}}>{{onePost.title}} {{delete-post}} 
    </li><br>

{{/each}}
</ul>

{{add-new-post}}
```

**delete-post.hbs**

```
<a class="ui red button" {{action 'deletePost' parentNode.id `}}>Delete</a>`
```

**delete-post.js**

```
    import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend
({
  actions:
  {
    deletePost(input)
    {
        alert(input);
    }   
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter by `=` operator like `{{component-name componentProperty=outerProperty`. In your case:

```
{{#each model as |onePost index|}}
   <li id = {{index}}>{{onePost.title}} {{delete-post parentNodeId=index}} 
   </li><br>
{{/each}}
```

Also, you should change `parentNode.id` to `parentNodeId` in your `delete-post.hbs`

Comment: @AmmarMZ, happy to hear that. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick icon on the left side of my answer.

Comment: Do you know how I can edit the parentNodeId directly in the posts.hbs. For example I'd like to append the number 1 using: parentNodeId = index + '1'